# Save photo to photo album

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, ios6

If i am displaying multiple images like this in my app

```
UIScrollView *imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfPhotos = 61;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPhotos; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    _imageView.tag = 122;
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

EDIT:

```
     imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

After adding the above statement to the code still it is not working.

```
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                       initWithTarget:self
                                                       action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];

    imageScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [imageScrollView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfPhotos, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Now after displaying images in scrollview if on any of the image within scrollview is long pressed will show action sheet with save photo button

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Save Photo", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet release];

}}


-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:

        [self savePhoto];

       break;

    default:
        break;

}}
```

When save photo button is pressed

```
-(void)savePhoto{


  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_imageView.image, self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
  }
```

but when executing the app it is not saving any photo to photo album. Am i missing some important piece of information to put in code to make it work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: The image view that you set the image for is a new instance that you allocate each time your for loop runs but the one your trying to save is the image property on the ivar for a property imageView. I don't think you ever set that.

Comment: You are very right. i did not notice that small pointer in my code. i fixed it like this imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
 but still not workin. I made change to my post please check it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

imageView and _imageView are two different vars. you're setting the image of imageView but when you're trying to get it, you're messaging _imageView, whose image property you never set.

EDIT:This is simpler. Just assign the gesture recognizer directly to the image view and then get your image view in handleLongPress:. Store a ref to that view in a selectedImageView property and then get the image property on that image view when you save. See my edits to your code.

```
Declare 

//a property to store a reference to the image view that the user selected
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *selectedImageView;

in viewDidLoad: self.imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIScrollView *imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfPhotos = 61;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPhotos; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    //make tag an incremented variable to ensure that all of the imageViews have a different tag
    _imageView.tag = i;

    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);


    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                       initWithTarget:self
                                                       action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];

    //I would add the gesture recognizer directly to the image view at this point. 
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;

imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfPhotos, self.view.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer{
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
//get the image view that the user selected and save it as your selectedImageView property
UIImageView *pressedImageView = (UIImageView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
self.selectedImageView = pressedImageView;

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Save Photo", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet release];

}}


-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:

        [self savePhoto];

       break;

    default:
        break;

}}


-(void)savePhoto{

//get the image from the imageView that you stored a reference to when the user selected it
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.selectedImageView.image, self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
  }
```

Comment: If you can please elaborate more in code terms i will appreciate that.